# simplyfing common data values (parts of a string) in an array - by merging same attributes (data values)

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I have arrays comprised of string elements like the following 2 examples. Each of the following lines is a string element of the array.

example1:

```
aaa bbb cc1 dd1 
aaa bbb cc1 dd2 
aaa bbb cc2 dd1 
aaa bbb cc2 dd2 
aaa bbb cc3 dd1 
aaa bbb cc3 dd2
```

example2:

```
bbb rrr nnn ttt ooo eee ddd fff contr 
bbb sss nnn ttt ppp eee contr 
bbb sss nnn aaa ooo eee ddd fff contr 
bbb rrr nnn ttt yyy eee ddd fff contr
```

I want to simplify and remove "redundant" lines by merging in a single line duplicate attributes. The goal is to have the fewest lines possible, without the data values being confusing. So the results should be:

example1:

```
aaa bbb cc1/c2/c3 dd1
aaa bbb cc1/c2/c3 dd2
```

example2:

```
bbb rrr nnn ttt ooo/yyy eee ddd fff contr 
bbb sss nnn ttt ppp eee contr 
bbb sss nnn aaa ooo eee ddd fff contr
```

(the results are an array as well).

My current approach goes like this: remove the first column then compare all elements. if equal lines are found, merge them. remove second column, compare. It becomes though somewhat complicated, as not all lines have the same number of data values (separated by spaces).

I'm stuck here. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Can you please formalize what you want to achieve? For example, it's unclear to me what should be the result for `a b1 c1, a b1 c2, a b2 c1`. Also, it's possible to further simplify the first example as `aaa bbb cc1/cc2/cc3 dd1/dd2`; exactly why didn't you do this? Even if it's not allowed, why didn't you merge `cc_` instead of `dd_`? It'll be less lines in the end.

Comment: @Dmitry thank you for your reply. The goal is to have as few lines as possible. Both `a b1 c1/c2, a b2 c1` AND `a b1/b2 c1, a b1 c2` are acceptable answers. No `aaa bbb cc1/cc2/cc3 dd1/dd2` is not allowed because one doesn't understand to which cc_ belongs dd2. You are right, the best merge would have been by cc_ like this `aaa cc1/cc2/cc3 d1, aaa cc1/cc2/cc3 d2` since it offers the fewest lines.

Comment: By `aaa bbb cc1/cc2/cc3 dd1/dd2` I mean that every `dd` belongs to every `cc` (i.e. there are $2 \times 3 = 6$ combinations, as we want). Still not allowed? Then do I understand correctly the problem is to minimize the number of lines, when each line can have only one compression term?

Comment: @Dmitry still not allowed yes. Yes the goal is to minimize the number of lines and each line has only one compression term

Comment: I thought about it, and I suspect it to be NP-hard. I tried a reduction from [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/22371/58531), but it didn't work out (not all such sets can be encoded as this problem).

Comment: @Dmitry I solved it

Comment: Can you please describe the solution (and why it returns an optimal answer)? Thank you.

Comment: @Dmitry I removed one column from each line, first the first column of data values. then found how many duplicates it has. I keep the total number of duplicates. then i remove second column. find again total number of duplicate lines. Then I keep the combination that has the most duplicate lines and reconstruct it by adding the missing values (from the removed column)

Comment: It won't produce the optimal answer. Consider an example `a1 b, a2 b, a3 b, a1 b1, a2 b2, a3 b3`. The optimal solution is `a1 b/b1, a2 b/b2, a3 b/b3` but you'll find `a1/a2/a3 b, a1 b1, a2 b2, a3 b3`.

Comment: @Dmitry No. I will find the optimal solution. Why? When I remove first column, the total number of duplicate lines (count more than 1) is 3 (column b). In second iteration when I remove the second column, the total number of duplicate lines is 6 (2 for a1, 2 for a2 and 2 for a3). For decision I use the highest number of duplicate lines. So I will construct `a1 b/b1, a2 b/b2, a3 b /b3`

Comment: If I understood correctly, even if you repeat the process (to handle `a1 b, a2 b, a b1, a b2`), it doesn't work in this example: https://pastebin.com/S89y0RPj

Comment: @Dmitry correct, in such a case it won't find the optimal one. Hm...

Comment: @Dmitry maybe the solution is this: make the decision for removal of first column. Then remove from table the merged lines. repeat until you don't find duplicates at all and just add the lines. Then start over, by removing second column. Construct the first table, remove the merged ones, continue to find duplicates in the remaining lines. In the end compare all results (different table each) and select the one with the least lines

Comment: You can do something like  this, but it'll take something like $O(n!)$ time in the worst case. With dynamic programming it can be improved to something like $O(2^n)$, but it's still exponential. On the other hand, I would I expect this problem to be NP-hard, so maybe it's the best we can do. Also note that it's not optimal to just merge everything you can in the column: you may merge some groups, but not others. TO see this, just consider the case when you problem consists of multiple independent problems, which have the same structure, but their columns are reordered.